# Plotting array file indexs with different slices in python

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, plot, slice

A have a structured array that contains multiple values. I want to plot various slices that are contained in the array in the same graph.

For example, I want a slice of the structured array like `data[:500]` for one of the y's and another slice of the data `data[500:1000]` for another y.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

path = '/users/username/Desktop/untitled folder/python files/file/'

os.chdir( path )

# Data  
data = np.load('file',mmap_mode='r')
# data.size: 167197
# data.shape: (167197,)
# data.dtype: dtype([('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4'),
# ('velx', '<f4'), ('vely', '<f4'), ('velz', '<f4'), ('m200', '<f4')])

x = np.arange(0,50000,500)
y = data[x]

plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(0,0))
plt.xlabel(r'$>10M_{\odot}$' )
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

The code above shows only one plot of the array.

If I attempt to plot slices, I run into problems that my y's will not have the same size and shape, throwing me off even more.

The size and shape of the array are 167197 and (167197,). So the ray has a long list of rows and one column.

I've tried:

```
x = np.arange(0,50000,500)
y = data[x,:500]
y1 = data[x,500:1000]
```

but it will give `IndexError: too many indices for array`

How would I go about this?

Comment: The shape (167197,) is telling you that you have 167197 rows and just one column. Then you are trying to get some rows (x array), from the columns between 500 and 1000 which doesn't exists in data array because you have just one column... sorry for my english :/

Comment: @user3926962 Not to sound rude, but I'm aware. If that is whats preventing me from what i am wanting to do.  How can i implement it with what i want?

Comment: oh, sorry then. I think you could try reshaping the "data" array to get what you want.

Comment: It's okay. Your english is well. Let me try your suggestion and ill reply how it turns out.

Comment: @user3926962 I tried emittating examples from this site http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html, but, i'm having no luck still.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood what you want to plot. Can you give me an example of your ideal plot ?

Comment: That's okay. I can tell you data that i am working with. So all the rows in the array are masses of different bodies from a cosmological simulation. So they are all varying values of same unit. What i want to do is take, say, 500 of the first values in the array and graph it on a plot. Then, taking a different slice of the masses in the array, say, [1000:1500] , and plot it along side with the other slice. I hope that gives a better understanding of what i want to accomplish and that it answers your question.

Comment: I think I managed to do [something](http://pastebin.com/H6p1xJJD) similar. Maybe changing "x" dimensions you could archieve what you are looking for. Now you have a (100,) shape in "x". You have to change it to 500 and do the splits in "y" like I do.

Comment: Brilliant my good sir!! Thank you. Be sure to post your reply as the answer down below so i can give a check and upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to solve this issue you have to change x dimensions to (500,) instead of (100,). Let's say:

```
x = np.arange(0,50000,100)
```

Then we do the slices as follows:

```
y = data[:500]
y2 = data[1000:1500]
```

So after that we have 500 different values on x and other 500 values on y and y2. Now we plot:

```
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, y2)
plt.show()
```

This is the result:

[image: plot_result]

I made a full example [here](http://pastebin.com/cNpGQzJQ). I hope that this solve your problem.

Cheers!